# Update the Nested Json with another Nested Json using php

Tags: php, json, foreach, dynamic-programming

I am new to PHP and have little experience with PHP arrays. I have the nested JSON data and I want to update some data with new data by the field id. I am trying to create dynamic sections with fields. There is a section id and field id and the new data will check the old JSON data by section and field id and then update it. Below is my complete code.
OR any other better way to update it?

```
$old_data= '
{
    "section_1":
    [
        {
            "text":{"class":"mb-20","name":"text","id":"field-id-11","value":"value 01","placeholder":"Section placeholder"}
        },
        {
            "textarea":{"class":"mb-20","name":"section_content","id":"field-id-12","value":"Section content 1","placeholder":"Section Content"}
        }
    ],
    "section_2":
    [
        {
            "text":{"class":"mb-20","name":"text","id":"field-id-1","value":"value amir 1","placeholder":"Section placeholder"}
        },
        {
            "textarea":{"class":"mb-20","name":"section_content","id":"field-id-2","value":"Section content 1","placeholder":"Section Content"}
        }
    ]
}';
```

Here below is my new data coming from a section.

```
$new_data= 
'{
    "section_1":
    [
        {"type":"text","id":"field-id-11","value":"Foot Ball"},
        {"type":"textarea","id":"field-id-12","value":"Awesome game!"}
    ],
    "section_2":
    [
        {"type":"text","id":"field-id-1","value":"New Data"},
        {"type":"textarea","id":"field-id-2","value":"Hello"}
    ]
}';
```

Here I am testing the old data with static new data and it is working fine. But I am confused how to marge the new data in the below foreach loop?

```
$sections = json_decode($old_data, true);
foreach ($sections as $section_id => &$section_fields)
{
    if($section_id == 'section_2')
    {
        foreach ($section_fields as &$section_fields_array)
        {
            foreach ($section_fields_array as $section_field_name => &$section_field_data)
            {
                if($section_field_name == 'text' && $section_field_data['id'] == '3454gfdgdgtd')
                {
                    $section_fields_array[$section_field_name]['value'] = "Foot Ball 2";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

At least with a fresh mind, I just fix the code. Checking by field id and then updating it.

```
$new_sections = json_decode($new_data, true);
$sections = json_decode($old_data, true);
foreach ($new_sections as $new_section_id => &$new_section_fields)
{
    foreach ($new_section_fields as $index => &$new_section_fields_data)
    {
        if($new_section_fields_data['id'] == $sections[$new_section_id][$index][$new_section_fields_data['type']]['id'])
        {
            $sections[$new_section_id][$index][$new_section_fields_data['type']]['value'] = $new_section_fields_data['value'];
        }
    }
}
```